# angular2 multipart image upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, api-design

I'm developing web application with *spring rest* and *angilar2*. I have such backend api (in pseudocode):

```
@POST
method create( @Json Data data, @Multipart Image img){
  ...........
}
```

I need an angular2 example relevant to this particular api.
Is it possible to send JSON and Image separately in one request?
Maybe I have to send Image within JSON as **byte[]**?
Either have to send two separate requests with data and image as below?:

```
@POST
method create(@Json Data data){
   ........ 
   return Id;
}

@POST
method uplodImg(Long id, Image img){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData to send data as well as image together in one request.
For eg:-

```
let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name", value);
        formData.append("file",this.file);
```

And you can access the file as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)

public String uploadLayoutFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestParam("name") string name)
{
.
.

}
```